# JavaScript shipping timer countdown

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript on my site that shows the amount of time left for an order to be placed for next day delivery.

```
if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
    pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
        var s = n.toString();
        return (new Array((len - s.length + 1)).join('0')) + s;
    };

    var timerRunning = setInterval(
        function countDown() {
            var now = new Date();
            if ((now.getDay() >= 1) && (now.getDay() <= 5)) { // Monday to Friday only
                var target = 15; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
                if (now.getHours() < target) { // don't do anything if we're past the cut-off point
                    var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
                    if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
                    var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
                    if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
                    var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
                    if (secs < 0) secs = 0;
                    var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
                    document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;
                }
            }
        }, 1000
    );
}
```

The problem with this is that on saturday and sunday it just displays 00:00:00 all the time.
What I would like it to do is count the hours over a weekend as is done on this site for example: http://www.nakedwines.com/full_site

JavaScript is really not my area and I'm totally at a loss on how I can change the code to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/rwet0o5f/

Comment: Could you please put that in a jsFiddle so we can play with it?

Comment: @frenchie http://jsfiddle.net/rwet0o5f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've moved the `now.getDay()` into variable and now it should be much more readable.

`weekday` contains 0 on Sunday, 1 on Monday and 6 on Saturday.
On Saturday we add 48 hours to the time of the deadline,
On Sunday we add only 24 hours.

http://jsfiddle.net/37ox54bk/7/

```
if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
    pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
        var s = n.toString();
        return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
    };

    var timerRunning = setInterval(

        function countDown() {
            var target = 15; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
            var now = new Date();

            //Put this in a variable for convenience
            var weekday = now.getDay();

            if(weekday == 0){//Sunday? Add 24hrs
                target += 24;
            }

            if(weekday == 6){//It's Saturday? Add 48hrs
                target += 48;
            }

            //If between Monday and Friday, 
            //check if we're past the target hours, 
            //and if we are, abort.
            if((weekday>=1) && (weekday<=5)){
                if (now.getHours() > target) { //stop the clock
                    return 0;
                }                
            }

            var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
            if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
            var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
            if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
            var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
            if (secs < 0) secs = 0;

            var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
            document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;

        }, 1000
    );
}
```

Comment: This works great but is it possible to make it correct on any time zone? for instance 2 hrs remaining in London shows 1 hr remaining in Paris. I need to show the same time remaining regardless of the country it is viewed in

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Instead of not doing anything when you are past the target time, I just increase the target time to point to a different day (the main difference is the if..else if statements at the beginning of the function)

```
function countDown() {
    var now = new Date();
    var target = 15; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
    if (now.getDay() == 0) { // Sunday - use tomorrow's cutoff
        target += 24;
    } else if (now.getDay() == 6) { // Saturday - use cutoff 2 days from now
        target += 48;
    } else if (now.getHours() < target) { // missed the cutoff point. Use tomorrow instead
        target += 24;
        if (now.getDay() == 5) { // Friday - use Monday cutoff
            target += 48;
        } 
    }
    var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
    if (hrs < 0)
        hrs = 0;
    var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
    if (mins < 0)
        mins = 0;
    var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
    if (secs < 0)
        secs = 0;
    var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
    document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;
}, 1000);
```

I forked the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vhah8yt/1/

Comment: Please explain what changed. Code only answers are generally frowned upon if it's not clear as to *why* it solves the problem.

Comment: @Qix: sorry about that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Code @sEver is good. Aj Richardson your code countdown is from new hours - is wrong.

I'd like to affter countdown hide HTML/CSS code.

Full Code: https://codepen.io/kamikstudio/pen/dyzvrQP

```
if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
    var s = n.toString();
    return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
};

var timerRunning = setInterval(

    function countDown() {
        var target = 14; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
        var now = new Date();

        //Put this in a variable for convenience
        var weekday = now.getDay();

        if(weekday == 0){//Sunday? Add 24hrs
            target += 24;
        }

        if(weekday == 6){//It's Saturday? Add 48hrs
            target += 48;
        }

        //If between Monday and Friday, 
        //check if we're past the target hours, 
        //and if we are, abort.
        if((weekday>=1) && (weekday<=5)){
            if (now.getHours() > target) { //stop the clock
                return 0;
            }                
        }

        var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
        if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
        var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
        if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
        var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
        if (secs < 0) secs = 0;

        var str = '<b>' + pad(hrs, 2) + ' </b>hours<b> ' + pad(mins, 2) + ' </b>min<b> ' + pad(secs, 2) + ' </b>sec';
        document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;

    }, 1000
);
```

}